# preg_replace to include a +, anything begins with string and ends with whitespace or period

Tags: php, preg-replace

I'm having a DEVIL of a time getting the preg_replace to work! The pattern is that it starts with "so+" and then it should replace that plus everything following.

```
so+FirstName, 
Your Reservation is confirmed for so+Date
```

Would be replaced with:

```
James,
Your Reservation is confirmed for July 1, 2017.
```

If it would help, I could use so: or so_ instead of the plus sign. But I need to replace anything that starts with that pattern, including what follows it, until it hits whitespace or a period.

EDIT: I've tried:

```
$search = '/\bso+([a-z]*)\b/i';
$search = '\bso+\w*\b';
```

Comment: That's a shame..... good luck fixing it.

Comment: What regular expressions have you tried? You need to at least demonstrate that you know what you're doing a little bit.

Comment: Edited to add previous use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this it's work  fine, the problem just in + ,add slash to banalize it

```
<?php
$string="so+FirstName,Your Reservation is confirmed for so+Date";
$string = preg_replace('/\bso\+([a-z]*),\b/i', 'James', $string);
$string = preg_replace('/\bso\+Date\b/i', date('M d,Y'), $string);
echo $string;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`+` is a special character, if you want to match it in your string you must use `\+`.